In my Next.JS app, why is adding the User model import to this file creating Module Not Found errors?
I'm building a Next.js app and ran into a road block. The second I add the User model to the file below (line 3) I get a bunch of errors like....
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
page: '/api/auth/_log'
and
Error: Cannot find module 'styled-jsx/package.json'
What I've tried:

Taking out the import line eliminates the errors, but I need the User model in this file.
I've tried npm install styled-jsx
I've tried deleting package.json and lock files and recreating through npm install
Googling the error messages and putting the errors into chat GPT for answers.
Discarded changes in git until I got to the exact line that was causing the issue.

AuthOptions.js
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import connectDB from '@/config/database'
import User from '@/models/User'; // <--- this is the line causing the problem

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                  prompt: "consent",
                  access_type: "offline",
                  response_type: "code"
                }
            }            
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {


        // Invoked on successful sign in
        async signIn({profile}) {
        // 1. Connect to databasee
        await connectDB()
        // 2. Check if user exists
        const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: profile.email})
        // 3. If not, then add user to database
        if (!userExists) {
        // truncate user name if too long
            const username = profile.name.slice(0,20)

            await User.create({
                email: profile.email,
                username,
                image: profile.picture,
            })
        }
        // 4. Return true to allow sign in
        return true

        }, //Modifies the session object
        async session({session}) {
            // 1. Ger user from database
            const user = await User.findOne({ email: session.user.email})
            // 2. Assign the user id to the session
            session.user.id = user._id.toString()
            // 3. return session
            return session
        }
    }
}

My User Model
import { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose'
import { unique} from 'next/dist/build/utils'

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: [true, 'Email already exists'],
        required: [true, 'Email is required']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Username is required']
    },
    image: {
        type: String
    },
    bookmarks: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Campaign'
        }
    ]
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const User = models.User || model('User', UserSchema)

export default User


I also implement the connectDB function here
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

let connected = false

const connectDB = async () => {
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true)

// If the database is already connnected, don't connect again.
    if (connected) {
        console.log('MongoDB is already connected...')
        return
    }

    // Connect to MongoDB
    try{
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
        connected = true
        console.log('MongoDB connected...')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }


}

export default connectDB

File structure:

Errors in the console:


I used a service called https://www.wyzant.com/ and got linked up with a Next.js expert. I don't represent them or anything, just how I reached out for help.
Solution:
Delete this line from User model:
 import { unique} from 'next/dist/build/utils'

Apparently this import that causes those files to all execute, thus causing my errors saying html was coming back where it expected json.
